# Constant #1064 error on everything I do in mySQL through phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

I've just done a fresh install of XAMPP and configured the usernames and passwords for phpMyAdmin and mySQL. So far so good, no errors and all working fine. But when I go to create a new database, create a new table, or even drop a table it always comes up with the #1064 Error message.

Error when dropping a database:

> SELECT MAX( version ) FROM.WHERE `db_name` =  'new_database_test' AND 
>   `table_name` =  '' AND FIND_IN_SET(  'DROP DATABASE', tracking ) >0
>
> MySQL said:
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE `db_name` = 'new_database_test'  AND `table_name` = '' 
>   AND FIND_IN_SET('D' at line 1

Error when creating a database:

> > SQL query:  Edit
> >
> > SELECT MAX( version ) FROM.WHERE `db_name` =  'new_test_db' AND 
> >     `table_name` =  '' AND FIND_IN_SET(  'CREATE DATABASE', tracking ) >0
> >
> > MySQL said:
> >
> > #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> >     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> >     near 'WHERE `db_name` = 'new_test_db'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND
> >     FIND_IN_SET('CREATE ' at line 1

Error when adding a table:

> SQL query:  Edit
>
> SELECT MAX( version ) FROM.WHERE `db_name` =  'new_test_db' AND 
>   `table_name` =  'awesome_table' AND FIND_IN_SET(  'CREATE TABLE',
>   tracking ) >0
>
> MySQL said:
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE `db_name` = 'new_test_db'  AND `table_name` =
>   'awesome_table'  AND FIND_IN' at line 1

Despite the errors it's showing the databases are getting created and dropped. But when I try to create a table it simply creates an empty table instead of including any of the columns I wanted.

Anybody have any idea how to fix this? I'm completely new to both mySQL and phpMyAdmin, so don't really know where to begin.

Thanks.

Comment: `FROM.WHERE` would seem to be your syntax problem, should be `FROM <tablename> WHERE` where to be valid syntax. Not that I understand what your SQL queries are about when manipulating databases...

Comment: I'm not running those queries. I'm simply using the phpMyAdmin gui to try and create a table and it pops up with those same errors over and over.

[link](http://i.imgur.com/ElSy76N.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen this problem on a couple of my students' machines, this year, while trying to teach them some basic SQL using XAMPP with PHPMyAdmin as an introductory user interface.

It seemed from the error message that PMA was appending nonsense SQL onto the end of the SQL statements when trying to open certain tables, even when clicking on their name in the sidebar.

Dropping the database and re-creating it didn't help, and unfortunately no obvious answers were forthcoming on my Google search.

After determining that the problem was PMA related, and likely related to user-specific configurations, I did a little digging around in the `phpmyadmin` database.

I found the nonsense SQL that was being appended to the queries in a row in the `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_uiprefs` which associated the problem with my student's username, and the specific database and table name that was causing her the trouble. Jackpot! I deleted this row.

After deleting that row, though, I tried shutting down and restarting Apache, MySQL, even my web browser, and the problem persisted. It wasn't until a total reboot of her machine that the problem vanished. (This was a Windows machine, FWIW, YMMV.)

Hope this helps.

Simón Ruiz

Canterbury

Technology

Answer (score 2):

Go to the table phpmyadmin->pma_table_uiperfs delete the rows that contains your table name. delete cookies, restart mysql engine.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me was:

```
1. go to table operations (where u clone or rename a table)
2. click on repair table (right side in table maintenance section)
```

EDIT:

actually what the problem is for me is lowercase table name and I used a uppercase select query ..

Answer (score 1):

To everyone giving answers that have nothing to do with the question - there is an error in PHPMyAdmin itself - somehow it is storing some bad SQL and appending it to every query, resulting in the error the OP describes, which i am experiencing now as well! there is one table in particular, when i try to browse it or select from it, i get the 1064 error with notes about a query that i am not making. the part where you see `ANDverifyOptionID>0` is not part of the query i am making - i am simply clicking the table and attempting to browse it:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use **near 'ANDverifyOptionID>0** 
>    LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

i suspect something is cached in PHPMyAdmin, but have no idea where to find it and fix it.

i have cleared cookies/restarted and no love. another user was able to view teh table with no issue - so this must be something related to a specific user account.

Does PHPMyAdmin cache something per user that could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the name of your table in all queries

```
      SELECT MAX( version ) FROM your_table 
                                    ^^-----your_table_here
```

and you dont have to include database or table in where clause . you need to learn the basics of select query.

Comment: I'm not running those queries. I'm just using the phpMyAdmin interface.

eg. [link](http://i.imgur.com/ElSy76N.png)

Comment: you should enter to `new_test_db` and then select max(version) if you have column called version in this table

Comment: There's no tables in the database. It won't let me add any columns to tables I create - So no column called version.

Comment: then enter to table and add columns there

Comment: It doesn't let me add any columns to the table.

Comment: when you go in database . you find under `Create table` just add the name of table and how much columns and you done

Comment: It doesn't let me do that (As stated in the original post). I think you're misunderstanding the problem Samir, it appears to be an issue with phpMyAdmin as **everything** I try to do causes the exact same error.

Comment: you can create tables via your php files also.

Comment: I understand how to create tables, everything works fine if I go through the command line. **But** when I try to do it all through phpMyAdmin it brings up these errors - Whether it's using the scripts on phpMyAdmin or the GUI.

Comment: this will help you to do your work in phpmyadmin http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_create_database.htm

Comment: Again, it's not that I don't know how to create something. It's that whatever I type, even if correct, it throws up those errors.