# Facing error 1064 in Mysql Phpmyadmin Web

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have created a database as well as table. But i am unable to open that table using Web. after clicking on that table.

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT* FROMdialer_rate LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

here `dialer_rate` is my table name.....but in the error there is no space between `FROM` and my table name..

Please help me to fix this

Comment: Can you please add more information about the version of PHPMyAdmin you are using

Comment: Think you have to add a blank after `from` `SELECT* FROM dialer_rate LIMIT 0, 25'`

Comment: show a screenshot, how do you call the statement.

Comment: i am not writing any query.......when i am clicking on that table..the error is coming.....

PHPMyadmin Version information: 4.2.11

Comment: anyone please help me.......also i have taken the screenshot...how can i attach......@Jens

Comment: Maybe the answer of **Simon** helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212584/constant-1064-error-on-everything-i-do-in-mysql-through-phpmyadmin Checking your `pma_table_uiprefs`

Comment: you do not enough reputation to upload image here.. upload image to imgur (anything you like) and put the url in the question

Comment: please find below url.......@learner

http://imgur.com/l6JfBgx

Comment: Version 4.2.11 is outdated.