# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; On PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

I get the Above Error when I select the click on the table . all other  tables get opened when click on that but only particular table is getting above error.
That table is opened through other Application but shows error on PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Add your query and table structure in your question.

Comment: Sometimes PhpMyAdmin creates invalid queries because it adds extra clauses. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212584/constant-1064-error-on-everything-i-do-in-mysql-through-phpmyadmin for example

Comment: try again and if still getting such type error then try to use this table by statement like desc db.table; in phpmyadmin query editor window and share what error you are getting.

Comment: Also, ensure that you have a recent version of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Error comes when I click on any particular table not at the time of execution of query. Other tables show structure when click on it.